# Find the area between $r = \tan ( \theta )$ and $r = -\theta$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$. Round your answer to the nearest thousandth

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I was trying to solve this problem, but I still can't wrap this around my head. When plugging this into a graphing calculator, I found three intersections, and since I couldn't find them algebraically by just setting them equal to each other, I tried graphing on rectangular mode to see where the functions intersect; however, this only further made me question the nature of the graphs since they only intersect twice on rectangular coordinates, whereas the polar graphs intersect three times. Can someone help me understand this? This is for a homework problem. Thanks.

Comment: Are there 5 intersection points and 2 regions?

Comment: Yes, but I am still confused on finding the bounds.

Comment: @zm_azad Numeric analysis. Use calculator.